# Upgrade Hazelcast 3.5.* to a newer version without losing data

Tags: java, hazelcast

From the Hazelcast official documentation, rolling upgrade is supported starting from version 3.8.

Provided my server version is 3.5, is there a way to create a successful cluster with new boxes running newer versions of Hazelcast?

Naively upgrading to 3.6.* resulted in 2 different clusters (old boxes still running 3.5 and another one with the new ones running 3.6 that obviously has no data as it was never able to touch base with the existing boxes).

My deployment process is as follows:

- create a new set of boxes
- remove the existing boxes one by one
- repeat with a second batch of boxes

My thoughts have gone towards storing a snapshot on disk / db and remount the partition / load from the DB at rollout time, but this might not even be supported and I'm hopeful there might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

What data structures do you use? For IMaps, ICaches and ILists, you can use Hazelcast Jet. It connects to the old cluster and pumps the data to the new cluster.
This works if your new cluster is on 3.x version. 3.x -> 4.x isn't possible this way. Use Jet 3.x version for it.

See https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/3.2.2/manual/manual.html#connector-imdg